# Wordpress: display $current_user->display_name in form readonly input field

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to display wordpress logged in username (display name) in form input field which is readonly.

I have gone through [Function Reference/wp get current user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) but no success.

look for my code which i tried:

```
public static function getFormHTML($form) {
    global $wpdb, $display_name;
     get_currentuserinfo();

$html = '<form>';

/*-------Below line in displaying user display name----------------*/

$html .= '<input  name="currentusr" value="' . $current_user->display_name. '"  type= "text"  readonly />';

$html = '</form>';
```

I am not able to figure out where i am doing wrong..

Please help me with solution...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `readonly`, try using the `disabled` attribute. For example:

```
$html .= '<input name="currentusr" value="' . $current_user->display_name . '" type="text" disabled />';
```

Comment: Where are you getting your `$current_user` object from? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: hey @henrywright, thank you for making point, i found error, as i was making mistake by not including `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` instead  of `get_currentuserinfo();`

Comment: `$current_user = wp_get_current_user()` is what I was expecting, but couldn't see it anywhere in your code :)